Where can I find the unreleased dingbats created by Hermann Zapf?

In 1977, Zapf created about 1000 (or over 1200 according to Linotype) sketches of signs and symbols. ITC chose from those a subset of 360 symbols, ornaments and typographic elements based on the original designs, which became known as ITC Zapf Dingbats.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapf_Dingbats

Where can I find the rest of these 1200 dingbats?

Its entirely possible that the answer is you can not. But they might be archived somewhere.

"Unreleased" implies they were never published. They may of course exist in some collection somewhere. Monotype eventually took over ITC. Perhaps ask them.
